# Como posso verificar se um coluna de um dataframe está contida em uma coluna de outro dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Olá, eu tenho a seguinte questão: eu tenho dois dataframes e quero verificar se os valores de uma coluna contem em outra coluna de outro dataframe que não tem o mesmo nome e nem a mesma ordem
uma coluna tem 22 mil linhas e a outra tem 48 mil linhas. No caso eu quero verificar se o id de uma coluna possui em outra e se sim retornar apenas as as linhas que correspondem.
Por exemplo o df1 tem uma coluna com os seguintes valores,

coluna = [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

no df2

coluna2 = ['1', '3']

quero retornar as linhas do df1 que contém os valores da coluna do df2

```
curso = cursos.where(cursos['CÓDIGO UNIDADE DE ENSINO'] == cursoAtivo['CO_UNIDADE_ENSINO']).notna()
```

Recebi o seguinte erro para o código acima
Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: pode fazer um exemplo mínimo replicável?

Comment: Oi Lucas, eu tentei explicar de forma mais clara. O nome das colunas não são idênticas

Comment: Você quer saber `coluna2` toda ou parte dela?

Comment: quero saber a coluna  toda

Comment: Para um palpite, seria algo assim `>>>df = curso.where(cursos['CÓDIGO UNIDADE DE ENSINO'].isin(cursoAtivo['CO_UNIDADE_ENSINO']))`, `>>>curso = df.dropna(0, subset=["coluna"], inplace=True)` .Peço que edite a pergunta e coloque uma amostra dos dois DataFrames envolvidos para que possa a apresentar uma resposta precisa e documentada.

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que é `coluna2` toda tem que estar dentro da `coluna`, acredito que a melhor forma seja usar `set.issubset()`.

### Criando dataframes de teste

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({"coluna": [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({"coluna2": [ '1', '3']})
```

### Dataframes

```
>>> df1
  coluna
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      4
4      5

>>> df2
  coluna2
0       1
1       3
```

### Criando sets

```
>>> c1 = set(list(df1["coluna"]))
>>> c2 = set(list(df2["coluna2"]))
```

### Checando se uma coluna está dentro de outra

```
>>> c2.issubset(c1)
True
```

**Nota Importante** O `set` é um conjunto sem repetição. Sendo assim, uma coluna cuja lista seja `[1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]` terá um set igual à `{1, 2}`. Sendo assim, caso você queira testar se a sequência `[1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]` está em outro dataframe, a solução apresentada não funcionará para este caso.